# Local Notification: No Permission to Play Sound Even After Registering fo UIUserNotificationTypeSound

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, ios8, xcode6, uilocalnotification

"Attempting to schedule a local notification UIConcreteLocalNotification: with a sound but haven't received permission from the user to play sounds"

```
- (void)registerForRemoteNotifications
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    } else{
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}

//added for ios8
- (void)successfullyRegisteredUserNotificationSettings
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

I followed the guide of other users in stackoverflow to use registerUserNotificationSettings for ios8. After invoking the function, I wait for the callback in AppDelegate: 
`- (void)application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:`
In the function, I call my successfullyRegisteredUserNotificationSettings method above to formally register.

Even after doing this, I still get the error. Can someone tell me why? Or has anyone encountered the same issue? How can this be solved?

Comment: So let me get this straight... didRegisterUserNotificationSettings calls successfullyRegisteredUserNotificationSettings which in turn calls registerForRemoteNotifications which in turn tries to register for notifications again? Don't understand that design, seems cyclic.

Comment: @BradThomas Mmm. First, you need to register the usernotificationsettings. after registering the settings, that's the time you can registerforRemoteNotifications.